Останавливается скроллинг при нажатии на RecyclerView
В своем проекте мне нужно было реализовать рандомный вертикальный автоскроллинг чисел.
Для этого я заблокировал нажатие на RecyclerView:
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }

Теперь пользователь сам не может скроллить RecyclerView, как и планировалось, но если он нажмет на Recycler - скроллинг остановится. Скроллю так:
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos)

Мне нужно, чтобы при касании юзера скролл не останавливался. Вообще заблокировать любые нажатия в рециклере. Как можно это реализовать?
